# Internal OAuth Error: Failed to fetch user profile NodeJs+passport-google-oAuth2

Tags: node.js, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth2

I'm learning Authentication using passport-google-oauth20. When I try registering a user using Google+, I keep on getting this error message after failing to submit the request (InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile).

I tried this solution:

1. I enabled Google+ API and waited.

2.Deprecated scopes

```
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
// save user sessionusing cookies
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

//initializa passport and use it to manage sessions
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const user = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// use static authenticate method of model in LocalStrategy
passport.use(user.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
        userProfileURL: "https: //www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"

    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        console.log(profile);
        user.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    }
));


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});
app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/secrets',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect secrets.
        res.redirect('/secrets');
    });

app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});
app.get("/secrets", function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated) {
        res.render("secrets");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});


app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    user.register({
        username: req.body.username
    }, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });
        }
    });

});


app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

    const user = new user({
        name: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.passwword
    });
    req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });
        }
    });

});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});ode here
```

Answer (score 2):

After breaking my head for 2 days found that , the issue is with node-auth package but node-oauth appears to be a dead project (the last commit was in 2017), and this bug is going to impact users of passport-google-oauth2 on fast connections. Please find issue explained below:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/87

I feel its better to implement google-Oauth without passport js.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33075782)

Answer (score 1):

With couple of changes, it worked for me.

1. In the passport.deserializeUser() method, you should be using 'user' not 'User'.
2. In the passport.use(new GoogleStrategy....) you have a typo in the userProfileURL value.

   userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"

Please try these changes. Hope that helps.
Note: also the default value for saveUninitialized is true. In your scenario, the value should be false, but true doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was just a typo in userProfileURL, I had it with a '0auth2', change it to 'oauth2' to  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error `"Failed to fetch user profile"` was caused by a bug in the grand-parent library `node-oauth`. Specifically, it was a double callback handling.

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/87

These libraries `passport-google-oauth2`, `node-oauth` are very old and not maintained well. And I didn't want to play with my own forks on GitHub. I quickly fixed it with a `package patch` approach.

https://dev.to/zhnedyalkow/the-easiest-way-to-patch-your-npm-package-4ece

How I applied a patch for the `node-oauth` library with `patch-package`:

1. Install `patch-package` library.
2. Patch `node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js` with the code:

```
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    // `www.googleapis.com` does `ECONNRESET` just after data is received in `passBackControl`
    // this prevents the callback from being called twice, first in passBackControl and second time in here
    // see also NodeJS Stream documentation: "The 'error' event may be emitted by a Readable implementation at any time"
    if(!callbackCalled) {
      callbackCalled= true;
      callback(e);
    }
  });
```

3. Run `npx patch-package node-oauth`.
4. Commit the patch file to my git repository.

Thanks [@patil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74270880/1983903) for the tip about the bug.

Comment: I enabled Google+ API but without luck. This patching package approach resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to use "**userProfileURL**" because the most recent version (v2.0.0) of the npm package resolves the Google+ account issue that existed a few years ago.